# Can't install angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4 package in NG 4.4.6 environment

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package, installation

I have an NG 4 project underway, and my package.json shows I'm running angular 4.4.6.  I am trying to add the **angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4** package as shown below, but I get the error below that I can't figure out how to resolve.

```
[root@vm-dev-fedora25x64 src]# npm install angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4 --save
myproject@1.2.3 /myproject/src
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.4.6
└─┬ angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4@0.2.0 
  ├─┬ @angular/platform-server@4.4.6 
  │ ├── parse5@3.0.3 
  │ └── xhr2@0.1.4 
  ├── @types/node@8.0.53 
  └─┬ ts-node@3.3.0 
    ├── minimist@1.2.0 
    └─┬ v8flags@3.0.1 
      └─┬ homedir-polyfill@1.0.1 
        └── parse-passwd@1.0.0 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angular-2-data-table@0.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

The error says unmet peer dependency angular/core@4.4.6 but I have that version installed!   And the last line suggests it is (also) trying to install the angular-2-data-table package which needs angular core 2.0.0.  What is going on?  How do I get the **angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4** package in?

The dependencies portion of my packages.json is:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.30",
"@types/ip": "0.0.30",
"@types/node": "^6.0.88",
"angular-2-data-table": "^0.1.2",
"angular-4-data-table": "^0.2.4",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"ip": "^1.1.5",
"ngx-loading": "^1.0.8",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.18"
```

Comment: add your package.json, or at least the dependencies section of it

Comment: You might need to pin your @angular/core version to be exactly 4.4.6 instead of ^4.4.6 (which would get newer versions). If you run `npm list` you will be able to see exactly which version you have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install this it will work all the latest version of angular

npm install angular-2-data-table --save